# SSIS- Set Multiple variables via a single SQL task

Tags: sql-server, variables, ssis

I'm trying to set multiple variables to the result of an SQL Query that returns a single row with multiple columns. The SQL statement is in the format of:

```
SELECT top 1 
    a,
    b, 
    c = x + y,
    d  
FROM tablename
WHERE aSwitch = 1
```

So I wish to use an 'Execute SQL Query' task which will set 4 package variables with the results of the query.

For example, if the results of the query were:

```
|    a    |     b   |    c    |  d  |
-------------------------------------
|   duck  |   cow   | rabbit  |  42 |
```

Then the state of the variables after execution would be:

```
var1 = duck
var2 = cow
var3 = rabbit
var4 = 42
```

Any ideas?

(using VS/SQL 2005)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the SQL task, under **General** menu, set the **ResultSet** property to **SingleRow**.

Then, in the **ResultSet** menu, add the variables in the order of your select clause and map the aliases with the variables. For exemple :

```
SELECT 1 AS One, 2 AS Two
```

[image]

Comment: This also works great. Is there any benefit to this method over the solution I posted out of curiosity?

Comment: Haha fair enough. I'll select this as the top answer then (Y)

Comment: Btw, what are you trying to achieve with the *c = x + y* ? In a select statement it doesn't make sense (except if you affect a local variable)

Comment: Its just another way of saying 'AS'. So the following two statements are synonymous: `SELECT x + y AS 'name` and `SELECT name = x + y` :)

Comment: Is ResultName = One, Two etc okay ? I thought we were supposed to use 0,1,2,3 etc. instead.

Comment: Use numbers starting from 0 if you don't specify column aliases. Otherwise, you can use column aliases in "Result Name"

Comment: I have an sp that returns two result sets of multiple rows, how can i fetch it into two variables. Any suggestions. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this by using mapping the result sets as a zero-based ordinal set. E.g. under 'Result Set' in the task properties:

```
result name   |   variable name
-------------------------------
     0        |       a
     1        |       b
     3        |       c
     4        |       d
```

This method allows me to keep my SQL statement unaltered also.

Answer (score -1):

Create one stored procedure with four output parameters:

```
CREATE SP_data(
  @x INT,
  @a int OUTPUT,
  @b int OUTPUT,
  @c int OUTPUT 
  @d int output
)
AS
  SELECT top 1 
    @a = a,
    @b= b, 
    @c  = x + y,
    @d= @d  
FROM tablename
WHERE Switch = @x
```

in the Execute SQL Query in the parameter mapping tab create four output parameters

the execute the proc

```
EXEXCUT SP_data 1,? OUTPUT,? OUTPUT,? OUTPUT, ? OUTPUT
```

Comment: Please check out my answer there is no need for a stored procedure